# Natural Cubic Spline beyond boundary guarantees constant slope?

Tags: interpolation, spline, python, extrapolation

my understanding is that for if I have five points, I can interpolate a natural cubic spline out of any five points with increasing x, because degree of freedom is five.

But when I try the python package, it seems not to be the case,

here are my five points

```
x = [-0.10093605653422201, -0.06729070435614802, 0.0, 0.06729070435614802, 0.10093605653422201]
y = [0.7701744  0.52964054 0.44325221 0.61695343 0.72468718]
```

And I used `scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline`

```
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
cs = CubicSpline(x, y, bc_type='natural')
x_plot = np.linspace(-0.16, 0.16, 100)
plt.plot(x_plot, [cs(xi) for xi in x_plot])
plt.show()
```

[image]

As the graph shows, the left boundary end point doesnt have a constant slope, why is that?

Comment: Cubic splines are called "natural" when the second derivative is zero at the boundary. It's not uncommon to see the spline extrapolated as a linear function, but it could be extrapolated by the cubics that lie on the first and last intervals. According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html), that's what is done by scipy (see the "extrapolate" argument). Note that usually you should not use the spline for extrapolation, so it should not be a concern.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671189/how-does-the-scipy-cubicspline-extrapolation-work-when-constraining-the-second-d